# Pass renewed commands by pdflatex engine

Tags: renewcommand

If I use:

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\oldtableofcontents\label{TOC}}
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\oldmaketitle\label{BODY}}}
```

in the `LaTeX` document (`.tex` file) it works.

But if it try to pass this string by `pdlatex` engine (I actually don't want to modify my document) in this way:

```
pdflatex "\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\oldtableofcontents\label{TOC}}\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\oldmaketitle\label{BODY}}} \
\nonstopmode \
\input{mydocument.tex}"
```

it doesn't work. I get:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\oldmaketitle ->\oldmaketitle 
                              \label {BODY}
l.176 \maketitle
                \flushbottom
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What's wrong in the `pdflatex` command?

**Note** I need to add the labels to make some test on page numbering using `\pageref` and the `.aux` file.

This is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\author{A. Uthor}

\title{Article's title}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{First section}
\blindtext

\subsection{First subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext

\subsection{Second subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsection{Third subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext

\section{Second section}
\blindtext
\subsection{First subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsection{Second subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsection{Third subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext

\section{Third section}
\blindtext
\subsection{First subsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Third subsubsection}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: does your document contain your patch too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes:-)

Comment: probably unrelated to the question but using `\let` on latex commands is not guaranteeed to work, betetr to use `\NewCommandCopy` also using `\label` after the toc can reference the wrong page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just tried `\NewCommandCopy` but I get the same error. In my tests `\label` works for my purpose.

Comment: you are doing the rename twice so will get the same error, on the `\label`,  on longer documents if there is a page break in the table of contents you normally want to reference the first page not the last

Comment: please always post the error message from code provided in the question. You are using a document which you have not shown with `\maketitle` on line 176

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry... I didn't notice that. About `labe`, I want refer to the last page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I think that the issue is not related to the document but to the technique.

Comment: That seems unlikely, but anyway if you provided an example it could be debugged (if we just invent a simple example it will work as intended)

Comment: even @egreg managed to create a simple example that doesn't error. Please fix the question to have an example of the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Ok.

Comment: the edited MWE produces no error when run with the command shown. The error message you show is still from a different document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I messed up with this issue. I'm so sorry. I tried to delete it but the system doesn't allow me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I consider the following test file

```
%%% patchgn.tex %%%
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\author{?}\title{??}


\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{something}

abc
\end{document}
```

and call `pdflatex` like

```bash
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\NewCommandCopy\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\oldtableofcontents\label{TOC}}\NewCommandCopy\oldmaketitle\maketitle\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\oldmaketitle\label{BODY}}} \input{patchgn}'
```

the produced `.aux` file is

```
\relax 
\newlabel{BODY}{{}{1}{}{}{}}
\newlabel{TOC}{{}{1}{}{}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}something}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

and no error is raised. I used single quotes rather than double quotes, but the result is the same.

Adding `\nonstopmode` doesn't change the business (I'd prefer to pass `-interaction=nonstopmode`, though).